# Spaghetti plot of random figures in

Tags: python, numpy, plot, random

I need a script which creates 3 plots in one frame ("spaghetti" plot) but current version returns something wrong.
What am I doing incorrectly?
Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[10]
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(500):
      i=np.random.randint(-100,100)
      a.append(i)
      b=np.cumsum(a)
      plt.plot(b)
plt.show
```

Comment: Indention is wrong and `plt.show` isn't actually calling anything. Is this what your original code has as well? Also, "something wrong" doesn't tell us anything. Explain your actual problem.

Comment: Please read the relevant matplotlib tutorials on [how to create and fill subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).

Comment: Hi Ted Klein. Yes, I have provided actual code. For i cycle creates a plot and For j cycle repeats it 3 times. So there must be 3 lines in one frame (spaghetti). Unfortunately I can't paste screenshots..

Comment: Hello Mr.T. I have reviewed tutorials with subplots but found nothing interesting.  But simple script a=[1,2,3]
b=[10,20,30]
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.show shows required format of chart

Comment: You shouldn't paste screenshots. You should transcribe (copy-paste) them into the question, which is possible by [edit]. No, you haven't provided the actual code as the code you've provided gives errors/results that are different from those you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected indents in For i cycle. Now it works

Comment: No it doesn't... Do you have `plt.show` in your original code? Because that line does nothing. Do you maybe have `plt.show()`?

Comment: And you're still missing the explanation of what is wrong with your current code.

Comment: There must be 3 different charts in one frame but the code returns only one.

Comment: if you want 3 separated charts then you have to use `subplots()`. And maybe first you should generate 3 separated list with values for 3 charts. And this moment you generate all values for single chart.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 3 separated charts in on window then you need `subplot(nrows, ncols, index)` to create new place before every plot.

I create 1 row with 3 columns (it gives 3 places, and `index` shows in which place I want to plot)

You have also wrong indentations - you should rather create `b` after generating all values in `a`, and you should create `a = [10]` inside first `for`-loop to create new list for new plot.

And finally - you forgot `()` in `plt.show()`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for j in range(3):
    a = [10]
    for i in range(100):
        value = np.random.randint(-100,100)
        a.append(value)
    b = np.cumsum(a)
    plt.subplot(1,3,j+1)
    plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It may need other settings to resize plots and set `0` in the same place.

---

If you need more plot then you may use `subplot()` to create grid - ie `subplot(3,3)` create 3 rows with 3 plot in every row.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for j in range(3):
    a = [10]
    for i in range(100):
        value = np.random.randint(-100,100)
        a.append(value)
    b = np.cumsum(a)
    plt.subplot(3,3,j+1)
    plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you mean 3 lines in one chart then you have to create new `a` for every line - but you use the same `a` for every line so finally they create one line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for j in range(3):
    a = [10]
    for i in range(100):
        value = np.random.randint(-100,100)
        a.append(value)
    b = np.cumsum(a)
    plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

BTW: `subplot()` gives `axis` - so you can first create all place and keep all `axis` and alter plot lines in places, and eventually update them

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

all_ax = []

for j in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3,3,j+1)
    all_ax.append(ax)

plt.ion()  # interactive ON (so `show()` will not block code)
plt.show() # show window  # plt.show(block=False)

while True:
    for j in range(9):
        a = [10]
        for i in range(100):
            value = np.random.randint(-100,100)
            a.append(value)
        b = np.cumsum(a)
        all_ax[j].clear()  # remove previous line
        all_ax[j].plot(b)
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Are there any options to put all graphs in one window if you have generated saying 10000 random graphs?

Comment: I don't understand question - use `subplot` for every graph (or image) to put it in the same window. If you use `subplot(100, 100, ...)` then they will create grid 100x100. I added exampl 3x3. I also added example how to update plots, and how to create 3 lines in one plot.

Comment: Hi furas. Your last update is answer on my question :) Many thanks for your help!